# Change the attachment storage directory in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-8

I have an Omnibus installation of Gitlab and by default it stores all attachments to `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads`.

Unfortunately the drive is pretty small and I would like to store the attachments on a different drive. Is there some configuration magic (or something else) that can make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change your omnibus configuration (`/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`) to customize that path, as described in "[Change default file locations](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/ab75b21c83a80d144716e63aa8731092af3eb0cc/doc/administration/high_availability/nfs.md#consolidating-mount-points)":

```
user['home'] = '/gitlab-data/home'
git_data_dir '/gitlab-data/git-data'
gitlab_rails['shared_path'] = '/gitlab-data/shared'
gitlab_rails['uploads_directory'] = "/gitlab-data/uploads"
gitlab_ci['builds_directory'] = '/gitlab-data/builds'
```

> To move the git home directory, all GitLab services must be stopped. Run `gitlab-ctl stop && initctl stop gitlab-runsvdir`.
>   Then continue with the reconfigure.
>
> Run `sudo gitlab-ctl` reconfigure to start using the central location. Please be aware that if you had existing data you will need to manually copy/rsync it to these new locations and then restart GitLab.